# swiftUI: detect intersection of two views embedded inside an array and swap their positions

Tags: swift, swiftui, intersection, drag

1) A number of instances of the same view are embedded inside an array. A Subview of a main ContentView displays them via ForEach in a HStack. Each instance has a geometry reader to detect frame intersections during drag. The goal is to swap views' positions on the main content view when intersection is detected. With the code below it's simply not detecting an intersection.

- Why?
- Is there a better/more simple way (than geometry reader) to detect collisions/intersections of views?
- Is there a better way (than array+foreach) to group & display a dynamic number of instances of some view?

  ```swift
  var rects: [rect] = [rect(num:"0"),rect(num:"1"),rect(num:"2")]

  struct rect: View {
      let id = UUID()
      let num: String
      @State var viewFrame: CGRect = .zero
      @State var viewOffset: CGSize = .zero
      var body: some View {
          Rectangle()
          .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
          .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
          .offset(viewOffset)
          .background(Text("\(num)"))
          .overlay(GeometryReader { r in
              Color.red
                  .opacity(0.5)
                  .onAppear {
                      self.viewFrame = r.frame(in: .global)
              }
          })
          .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
              .onChanged { value in
                  self.viewOffset = value.translation
          }
              .onEnded { value in
                  let newFrame = self.viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: self.viewOffset.width, dy: self.viewOffset.height)
                  if let swap_rect = rects.first(where: {$0.id != self.id && $0.viewFrame.intersects(newFrame)}) {
                      print("intersects")
                      rects.swapAt(rects.firstIndex(of: self), rects.firstIndex(of: swap_rect))
                  } else {
                      print("nope")
                  }
                  self.viewOffset = .zero
          }
          )
      }
  }

  struct field: View {
      var body: some View {
          HStack {
              ForEach(self.field_env.rects, id:\.id) { rect in
                      rect
              }
          }
      }
  }

  struct ContentView: View {
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
              field()
          }
      }
  }
  ```

2) The only way I was **somewhat** able to achieve this is by storing additional GR collision frame of each view inside a published array var of environmentObject/ObservableObject. However, once two instances of my view swap their positions on the main view, it seems GR collision frame CGRects are not getting updated (as GR only has onappear method) and next time I perform view drag & intersect wrong views are swapped (not the ones visually collided) e.g. the code below displays 3 rectangles labeled 0,1,2 (as their indexes in the array). First time you drag "2" onto "1" they swap correctly, but then if you drag "1" onto "2" the "1" gets swapped with "0".

````
```swift
class FieldEnv: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rect_frames: [UUID:CGRect] = [:]
    @Published var rects: [rect] = [rect(num:"0"),rect(num:"1"),rect(num:"2")]
}

struct rect: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    let id = UUID()
    let num: String
    @State var viewFrame: CGRect = .zero
    @State var viewOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
        .offset(viewOffset)
        .background(Text("\(num)"))
        .overlay(GeometryReader { r in
            Color.red
                .opacity(0.5)
                .onAppear {
                    self.viewFrame = r.frame(in: .global)
                    self.field_env.rect_frames[self.id] = r.frame(in: .global)
            }
        })
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { value in
                self.viewOffset = value.translation
        }
            .onEnded { value in
                let newFrame = self.viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: self.viewOffset.width, dy: self.viewOffset.height)
                if let swap_rect = self.field_env.rect_frames.first(where: {$0.key != self.id && $0.value.intersects(newFrame)}) {
                    print("intersects")
                    withAnimation {
                        self.field_env.rects.swapAt(self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(of: self)!, self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == swap_rect.key})!)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("nope")
                }
                self.viewOffset = .zero
        }
        )
    }
}

struct field: View {
    let NC = NotificationCenter.default
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(self.field_env.rects, id:\.id) { rect in
                    rect
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            field()
        }
    }
}
```
````

UPDATE:

I've tried manually updating GR view frames after the swap is performed via notification center as I thought that GR was using initial frame positions (obtained during .onAppear) every time and things got confused after the swap, but it seems the problem is somewhere else - still wrong array indexes are getting swapped (not the ones that belong to the intersected views):

````
```swift
struct rect: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    let NC = NotificationCenter.default
    let id = UUID()
    let num: String
    @State var viewFrame: CGRect = .zero
    @State var viewOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
        .offset(viewOffset)
        .background(Text("\(num)"))
        .overlay(GeometryReader { r in
            Color.red
                .opacity(0.5)
                .onAppear {
                    self.viewFrame = r.frame(in: .global)
                    self.field_env.rect_frames[self.id] = r.frame(in: .global)
                    self.NC.addObserver(forName: .cardsSwapped, object: nil, queue: nil, using: {_ in self.field_env.rect_frames[self.id] = r.frame(in: .global)})
                }
        })
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { value in
                self.viewOffset = value.translation
        }
            .onEnded { value in
                let newFrame = self.viewFrame.offsetBy(dx: self.viewOffset.width, dy: self.viewOffset.height)
                if let swap_rect = self.field_env.rect_frames.first(where: {$0.value.intersects(newFrame)}) {
                    print("intersects")
                    withAnimation {
                        self.field_env.rects.move(fromOffsets: [self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(of: self)!], toOffset: self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == swap_rect.key})!)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("nope")
                }
                self.viewOffset = .zero
                self.NC.post(name: .cardsSwapped, object: nil)
        }
        )
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement `onMove`? Better user the built-in re-ordering feature (by using `ForEach` inside `List`). For details see the docs or this [short tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-move-rows-in-a-list)

Comment: thank you. Yes, kind of. The problem is that it seems in the tutorial provided by you the actual drag is enabled by the navigationview and it has certain restrictions for how can you actually drag the item inside the navigationview. I'd like my rectangles to be freely draggable so that onMove (or whatnot) is triggered upon a collision with any object on the main view. In the matter of fact i've tried using the array.move method instead of my array.swapAt method but the result is the same - the swap is triggering when GR view frames intersect but wrong views are getting their positions swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this time it's working properly...however the solution itself and amount of overhead code far from being perfect, not sure maybe there's more easy way - please take a look, all ideas welcome

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Notification.Name {
    static let viewModified = Notification.Name("view_modified")

}

class FieldEnv: ObservableObject {
    @Published var rect_frames: [CGRect] = []
    @Published var rects: [Int] = [0,1,2]
}


struct rect: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    let num: Int
    @State var viewOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 100)
        .overlay(Text("\(num)"))
        .offset(viewOffset)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged { drag in
                self.viewOffset = drag.translation
        }
            .onEnded { drag in
                if let swap_rect_i = self.field_env.rect_frames.firstIndex(where: {$0.contains(drag.location)}) {
                    print("intersects")
                    withAnimation {
                        self.field_env.rects.swapAt(self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(of: self.num)!, swap_rect_i)
                        self.viewOffset = .zero
                    }

                } else {
                    print("nope")
                    self.viewOffset = .zero
                }

        }
        )
    }
}


struct field: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    let NC = NotificationCenter.default
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(self.field_env.rects, id:\.self) { num in
                rect(num: num)
                .background(GeometryReader { r in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            self.NC.post(name: .viewModified, object: nil)
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            self.NC.post(name: .viewModified, object: nil)
                        }
                    .onReceive(self.NC.publisher(for: .viewModified, object: nil), perform: {_ in
                        self.field_env.rect_frames = [CGRect](repeating: .zero, count: self.field_env.rects.count)
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                            self.field_env.rect_frames[self.field_env.rects.firstIndex(of: num)!] = r.frame(in: .global)
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.field_env.rect_frames = [CGRect](repeating: .zero, count: self.field_env.rects.count)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var field_env: FieldEnv
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            field()
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {self.field_env.rects.append((self.field_env.rects.max() ?? 0)+1)}) {
                    Text("Add 1")
                }
                Button(action: {self.field_env.rects.removeLast()}) {
                    Text("Del 1")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but there is some redundancy that I removed and still had it working. 

I cant work out why you are reseting all rect_frames in the .onRecieve method or why there is a dispatch there.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan, I am not sure how helpful this might be but, for what it's worth, you might take a look at the Swift on Sundays project that Paul Hudson created called Switcheroo.  It is a game where you have a tray of letters to choose from and you drag a letter from the tray to replace one of 4 letters above to make a new word. I'm assuming that this has a collision of sorts that might be of use to you. You can find the project on GiHub here: https://github.com/twostraws/SwiftOnSundays

Comment: hm, it seems there's still some bug here and i can't figure it out. When the array count is constant (as in the switcheroo example project) everything is working perfect. However, when I add/remove items from the array it seems their geometry reader frames in the dedicated array somehow become unaligned with the actual array that i run ForEach against. I'm wondering how can I force re-rendering of the entire view body so that geometry reader frames are updated with fresh CGRect data

Answer (score 0):

ok finally i've managed to make it work. I've decided to adopt Paul's concept of storing the **strings** in the array instead of complete **views**, and actually creating the views during the ForEach loop using those strings. Somehow after that the swapping started to work properly (i.e. with proper indexes). To increase precision, i've also replaced .intersects with .contains. So thanks to Chrispy for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: hm, it seems there's still some bug here and i can't figure it out. When the array count is constant (as in the switcheroo example project) everything is working perfect. However, when I add/remove items from the array it seems their geometry reader frames in the dedicated array somehow become unaligned with the actual array that i run ForEach against. I'm wondering how can I force re-rendering of the entire view body so that geometry reader frames are updated with fresh CGRect data